# How do I make a dictionary with multiple keys to one value?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a question about a dictionary I want to make. My goal is to have multiple keys to a single value, like below:

```
dictionary = {('a', 'b'): 1, ('c', 'd'): 2}
assert dictionary['a'] == 1
assert dictionary['b'] == 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @evil_inside, ah, if that's what you want, why don't you just assign 1 to both keys?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974022/is-it-possible-to-assign-the-same-value-to-multiple-keys-in-a-dict-object-at-onc

It may be helpful

Comment: @Eli, that is not a duplicate. In fact that link is a duplicate of this. Look at the times of the posts.

Answer (score 44):

I guess you mean this:

```
class Value:
    def __init__(self, v=None):
        self.v = v

v1 = Value(1)
v2 = Value(2)

d = {'a': v1, 'b': v1, 'c': v2, 'd': v2}
d['a'].v += 1

d['b'].v == 2 # True
```

- Python's strings and numbers are *immutable* objects,
- So, if you want `d['a']` and `d['b']` to point to **the same value** that "updates" as it changes, make the value refer to a *mutable* object (user-defined class like above, or a `dict`, `list`, `set`).
- Then, when you modify the object at `d['a']`, `d['b']` changes at same time because they both point to same object.

Comment: You don't have to use an immutable object, simply assign the value using the same variable (reference to the object) and you will get the same result for both mutable and immutable objects e.g `num = 2` and not the object directly (`num` is the variable and `2` is the object). You can test it by using the `is` keyword, like so: `if d['a'] is d['b']: `. if both keys are pointing to the same object then the expression will be  `True`

Comment: @Yomi This will not work with assigning new (immutable) objects! They might point to the same object initially (with integers, even when you put the literal value there). But try reassigning the value of `d['a']` to a different integer variable and see that `d['b']` will not have changed. It doesn't matter if you use the variable name or the literal number because it assigns a new (immutable) object to only the one dictionary entry and not the other. It doesn't know which key has the same object as value and which should also change to point to the other object.

Answer (score 20):

If you're going to be adding to this dictionary frequently you'd want to take a class based approach, something similar to @Latty's answer in this SO question [2d-dictionary-with-many-keys-that-will-return-the-same-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336952/2d-dictionary-with-many-keys-that-will-return-the-same-value).

However, if you have a static dictionary, and you need only access values by multiple keys then you could just go the very simple route of using two dictionaries. One to store the alias key association and one to store your actual data:

```
alias = {
    'a': 'id1',
    'b': 'id1',
    'c': 'id2',
    'd': 'id2'
}

dictionary = {
    'id1': 1,
    'id2': 2
}

dictionary[alias['a']]
```

If you need to add to the dictionary you could write a function like this for using both dictionaries:

```
def add(key, id, value=None)
    if id in dictionary:
        if key in alias:
            # Do nothing
            pass
        else:
            alias[key] = id
    else:
        dictionary[id] = value
        alias[key] = id

add('e', 'id2')
add('f', 'id3', 3)
```

While this works, I think ultimately if you want to do something like this writing your own data structure is probably the way to go, though it could use a similar structure.

Answer (score 12):

Your example creates multiple key: value pairs if using `fromkeys`. If you don't want this, you can use one key and create an alias for the key. For example if you are using a register map, your key can be the register address and the alias can be register name. That way you can perform read/write operations on the correct register.

```
>>> mydict = {}
>>> mydict[(1,2)] = [30, 20]
>>> alias1 = (1,2)
>>> print mydict[alias1]
[30, 20]
>>> mydict[(1,3)] = [30, 30]
>>> print mydict
{(1, 2): [30, 20], (1, 3): [30, 30]}
>>> alias1 in mydict
True
```

Answer (score 5):

It is simple. The first thing that you have to understand the design of the Python interpreter. It doesn't allocate memory for all the variables basically if any two or more variable has the same value it just map to that value.

let's go to the code example,

```
In [6]: a = 10

In [7]: id(a)
Out[7]: 10914656

In [8]: b = 10

In [9]: id(b)
Out[9]: 10914656

In [10]: c = 11

In [11]: id(c)
Out[11]: 10914688

In [12]: d = 21

In [13]: id(d)
Out[13]: 10915008

In [14]: e = 11

In [15]: id(e)
Out[15]: 10914688

In [16]: e = 21

In [17]: id(e)
Out[17]: 10915008

In [18]: e is d
Out[18]: True
In [19]: e = 30

In [20]: id(e)
Out[20]: 10915296
```

From the above output, variables a and b shares the same memory, c and d has different memory when I create a new variable e and store a value (11) which is already present in the variable c so it mapped to that memory location and doesn't create a new memory when I change the value present in the variable e to 21 which is already present in the variable d so now variables d and e share the same memory location. At last, I change the value in the variable e to 30 which is not stored in any other variable so it creates a new memory for e.

so any variable which is having same value shares the memory.

> Not for list and dictionary objects

let's come to your question.

when multiple keys have same value then all shares same memory so the thing that you expect is already there in python.

you can simply use it like this

```
In [49]: dictionary = {
    ...:     'k1':1,
    ...:     'k2':1,
    ...:     'k3':2,
    ...:     'k4':2}
    ...:     
    ...:     

In [50]: id(dictionary['k1'])
Out[50]: 10914368

In [51]: id(dictionary['k2'])
Out[51]: 10914368

In [52]: id(dictionary['k3'])
Out[52]: 10914400

In [53]: id(dictionary['k4'])
Out[53]: 10914400
```

From the above output, the key k1 and k2 mapped to the same address which means value one stored only once in the memory which is multiple key single value dictionary this is the thing you want.  :P

Comment: I believe that this is only because Python stores objects of the smaller numbers so that they do not have to be recreated every time. If you were to store more complex data, such as larger numbers or strings etc, this would not be the case.

Comment: This is not an answer, and a bad direction. It doesn't even do what OP wanted: `dictionary['k2'] = 3` makes `'k2'` map to 3 while `'k1'` still maps to 1. This ID stuff is but a mere curiosity of how Python works under the hood. Python is not C, you can't hack around with pointers and expect it to work. Even in places where it may work as intended (not the case here), it should absolutely never be used at all in any code that has ever seen a production code from a distance.

Answer (score 1):

**HAVING MULTIPLE KEYS**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def get_keys(s):
    # Lower the user's entry to easily manipulate data
    s = s.lower()
    
    # Create a list to simulate multiple keys
    numbers = ['uno', 'one', 'um', 'eins', 'ein']
    
    # Lambda for input validation
    validator = lambda key: key if key in numbers else 'no-key-found'  # return me x if x is found in the list numbers, contratiwise return me 'no-key-found'
    
    dic = {
        validator(s):'1',
        'no-key-found':'Key does not exist'
    }
    
    
    return dic[validator(s)]


print(get_keys(input('Type in word: ')))
```

***HAVING DYNAMIC KEYS***

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys


def week_days():
    # Assets
    number_day = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
    
    # Introduction
    print('Welcome to the Week Day Finder')
    
    # User input
    day = input('Please, enter the day you want to check: ').lower()
    WEEK_COLOR = {'RED': '\u001b[31m', 'GREEN': '\u001b[32m'}
    
    # Day validator
    days = {
        '1' if day in number_day else 'sunday': 'Weekend Day',
        '2' if day in number_day else 'monday': 'Week Day',
        '3' if day in number_day else 'tuesday': 'Week Day',
        '4' if day in number_day else 'wednesday': 'Week Day',
        '5' if day in number_day else 'thursday': 'Week Day',
        '6' if day in number_day else 'friday': 'Week Day',
        '7' if day in number_day else 'saturday': 'Weekend Day'
    }
    
    # Logical trial
    try:
        if days[day] == 'Week Day':
            print(WEEK_COLOR['GREEN'], days[day])
            
        else:
            print(WEEK_COLOR['RED'], days[day])
            
    except KeyError:
        print('** Invalid Day **', file=sys.stderr)
        
        
def main():
    week_days()
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Having fun for using the destructuring assignment:

```
dictionary = {
  **dict.fromkeys(['a', 'b'], 1),
  **dict.fromkeys(['c', 'd'], 2),
  }

assert dictionary['a'] == 1
assert dictionary['b'] == 1

# Elegant!!
```