# use two items as key to create dictionary python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make a dictionary with multiple keys to one value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123853/how-do-i-make-a-dictionary-with-multiple-keys-to-one-value)

I have 5 columns of data,

```
 usermac, useragent, area ,videoid, number of requests
```

I want to use both (usermac,useragent) as key to create a dictionary, since unique combination of (usermac, useragent) represents a unique user.

so the dictionary would be like:

```
 usermac1, useragent1: area1, videoid1, 10
                       area1, videoid2, 29
 usermac1, useragent2: area1, videoid1, 90
                       area1, videoid2, 34

                        ...
```

I only know how to create a dictionary with only one item as key. so can anyone help?

my code is:

```
    for line in fd_in.readlines():
        (mac, useragent, area, videoid, reqs) = line.split()

    video_dict = d1.setdefault((mac,useragent) {})
    video_dict.setdefault(videoid, []).append(float(reqs))
```

and it has syntax error:

```
    video_dict = d1.setdefault((mac,useragent) {})
```

Comment: @jamylak maybe I should have added my code, I have some syntax error in the code, so I'd appreciate your help, thanks

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use any (hashable) object as a key for a python dictionary, so just use a tuple containing those two values as the key.

Comment: Just look out if you are planning to serialize the dictionary.  For example, `json.dumps(mydict)` is going to fail.

Answer (score 32):

I believe you can use a tuple as the key for the dictionary. So you'd have

```
mydict = {}
mydict[(usermac1,useragent1)] = [ [area1, videoid1, 10],[area1,videoid2,29]... ]
```