# print value for matching multiple key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have multiple keys mapped to a single value. If any key matches then print the corresponding value. This is only the gist of what I want to do and not the actual code.

```
responses = {
    ("hi","Yo"):"Lets get started."
}

def get_response(user_message):
    if user_message in responses:
        user_message = responses[user_message]
    print(user_message)

get_response("hi") #should print 'Lets get started'
get_response("Yo") #should print 'Lets get started'
```

Also is this the right way of storing multiple keys to a single value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a dictionary with multiple keys to one value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123853/how-do-i-make-a-dictionary-with-multiple-keys-to-one-value)

Comment: @Sushanth I used the mentioned answer to create the dict, but for comparing and retrieving the value I have no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish what you're trying to do, you would have to check whether "hi" is `in` the tuple. (`("hi", "Yo")` is a tuple).

So you can do something like this:

```
for key in responses:
    if user_message in key:
        print(responses[key])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your `get_response` method.

```
responses = {
    ("hi", "Yo"): ["Lets get started."]
}


def get_response(user_message):
    print([values for keys, values in responses.items() if user_message in keys][0][0])


get_response("hi")  # should print 'Lets get started'
get_response("Yo")  # should print 'Lets get started'
```

Output:

```
Lets get started.
Lets get started.
```