# Multi key dict not working on some strings

Tags: python, dictionary, python-import, qgis

I want iterating on dict key as explained in the  [SilentGosht](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2974082/1958558) answer.
But on some strings i get error.
My environment is QGIS 2.14 python terminal

Here is my dict:

```
dictAliases = {
('ID_WS_INT','ID_WS'): 'B1',
('PGM_START','PGM_START_DATE','PGM_START_'): 'Debut programme'
}
```

Here my code to iterate on dict:

```
next(v for k, v in dictAliases.items() if 'PGM_START_' in k)
```

It works fine

BUT if put the dict in a separate file and import it as:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('C:\workspace\script')
import osirisdict
next(v for k, v in osirisdict.dictAliases.items() if 'ID_WS_int'in k)
```

I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    StopIteration

It's only on some strings as *ID_WS_int* in place of *ID_WS_INT* or *PGM_START_* in place of *PGM_START_DATE*

I can't understand why the import changes things

here is the imported dict:

```
dictAliases = {
('ID_WS_INT','ID_WS'): 'B1',
('PGM_START','PGM_START_DATE','PGM_START_'): 'Debut programme',
('IMP_TYPE_F','IMP_TYPE_FR'): 'Type impetrant',
('PGM_START','PGM_START_DATE','PGM_START_'): 'Debut programme',
}
```

Comment: `if 'ID_WS_int'in k` doesnt work because casing matters. Write `if 'ID_WS_INT' in k`

Comment: BTW use raw strings for windows paths or you'll have surprises: `sys.path.append(r'C:\workspace\script')`

Comment: OK, Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import has nothing to do with that.

`in` in the list checks for exact string match.

The first example works `PGM_START_` because you're respecting the case.

In the second case, since your string only matches if we disregard case, `in` fails to find the item in the `tuple`, the generator is empty, and you're getting the `StopIteration` error.

Quickfix for that one:

```
next(v for k, v in osirisdict.dictAliases.items() if 'ID_WS_INT' in k)
```

If you don't know about the case, you could fix it the way below using `any` and comparing `uppercase` versions of the items in the keys:

```
next(v for k, v in dictAliases.items() if any('ID_WS_INT'==i.upper() for i in k))
```

But it's still a very non-performant way to perform lookups, you're not using the dictionary lookup speed at all.

I suggest that you build a new dictionary, with 1 key (uppercased) by tuple item:

```
newdict = {k.upper():v for t,v in dictAliases.items() for k in t}
```

which gives for `newdict`:

```
{'PGM_START_DATE': 'Debut programme', 'ID_WS_INT': 'B1', 'PGM_START_': 'Debut programme', 'PGM_START': 'Debut programme', 'ID_WS': 'B1'}
```

Then you can access the elements using `get`:

```
newdict.get('ID_WS_INT')
```

(which returns `None` if not found). That'll be more efficient and more pythonic.

Comment: OK, Thank you. The creation of a new dict works perfectly but sorry i cannot add +1, no points enough

Comment: The 'newdict = {k.upper():v for t,v in dictAliases.items() for k in t} ' generates wrong key values. It takes the first letter of the real key in place of the key itself. But i let the point because i think this is not totally wrong.

Comment: this formula applied to your data gives `{'PGM_START_DATE': 'Debut programme', 'ID_WS_INT': 'B1', 'PGM_START_': 'Debut programme', 'PGM_START': 'Debut programme', 'ID_WS': 'B1'}` so it's correct. I have tested it. Did you change your input data?

Comment: No, but it was just an extract because i have more than 50 lines. But i created a new dict with a line by key for the same value and it works.

Comment: good. Next time you have an issue with an answer, it's okay to unaccept, but it's better to ping the poster so he/she can fix that. Some posters would barely have noticed the unacceptance and you wouldn't have had your solution. Whatever. Cheers for that.