# Dictionary with multiple keys mapping to same value

Tags: python, dictionary, lookup-tables

I have a need to take an integer value and index into a table of corresponding strings. In this case, contiguous ranges of integers should all map to the same string. Something like (with a non-working dictionary example):

```
int_dict = { 0              : "String1",
             1              : "String2",
             2              : "String3",
             range(3,15)    : "String4",
             16             : "String5"   };
```

As expected, using `range` here just fails and trying to use lists gives the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`.

Perhaps a dictionary is not the best data structure for this task. My question, then, is how can something like this be easily done? The ranges tend to be quite large, so doing this via manual definition (unless something like `range` can be used) is not an option.

Comment: That's not what a dictionary is defined for. Dictionaries do equality checks. You can use a datastructure called an *interval tree*, which does lookup in *O(log n)*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, That was my original conclusion. There seems to be ways to [make it work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974022/is-it-possible-to-assign-the-same-value-to-multiple-keys-in-a-dict-object-at-onc#2974082), though. I'll check out _interval trees_.

Comment: yes but this will simply generate a key for every element in `range(..)` so if you range over millions of elements, the dictionary will blow up. Of course that will work (given Python has enough memory).

Comment: How about a list of tuples

Comment: @KHELILIHamza Then you'll need the tuple for lookup, not a single value.

Comment: @KHELILIHamza, The underlying data structure is less important. I effectively need something that provides `datastruct[5] => "TheString"`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39358092/range-as-dictionary-key-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it what you want to achieve  ?

```
int_dict = { 0              : "String1",
             1              : "String2",
             2              : "String3",
             16             : "String5"   };
#range is first inclusive last exlusif, watch out for that
for i in range(3,15)    :
    int_dict[i] = "String4"
```

output :

```
{0: 'String1',
 1: 'String2',
 2: 'String3',
 3: 'String4',
 4: 'String4',
 5: 'String4',
 6: 'String4',
 7: 'String4',
 8: 'String4',
 9: 'String4',
 10: 'String4',
 11: 'String4',
 12: 'String4',
 13: 'String4',
 14: 'String4',
 16: 'String5'}
```

Edit : you can also use tuple as key

```
int_dict = { (0,0)              : "String1",
             (1,1)              : "String2",
             (2,2)              : "String3",
              (3,15)             :"String4",
             (16,16)             : "String5"};

def ValueInDict(value):
    for i,j in int_dict.items():
        if value >= i[0]:
            if value <= i[1]:
                print(j)
                return
    print("NOT THERE")

ValueInDict(5)
```

ouput :

```
 String4
```

Comment: This is useful, but I was hoping there may be some supported syntax for doing this. Like using `range`. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @sherrellbc, maybe you can use tuple as key  ? then you can check if it is within

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a special syntax for that rare case. But you can create a `dict` with a range of keys and the values you want. And add it to you `int_dict` using `update`.

```
int_dict = {
    0: "String1",
    1: "String2",
    2: "String3",
    16: "String5"
}
int_dict.update({i: "String4" for i in range(3, 16)})
```

Answer (score 1):

With dict comprehension:

```
int_dict = {n:'String{}'.format(n+1) for n in range(0,4)}
int_dict.update({n:'String4' for n in range(3,16)})
int_dict.update({16:'String5'})
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose a solution that I find more pythonic: first a dictionary with the keys having different values is created, then it is updated with a dictionary the keys having the same values by using `dict.fromkeys`

```
int_dict = {
    0: "String1",
    1: "String2",
    2: "String3",
    16: "String5"
}
int_dict.update(dict.fromkeys(range(3,15), "String4"))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about nested dictionaries? First level key being left side of the interval and second level key being the right side?

```
d = {0:{0:"String1"},
...
 3:{15:"String4"},
 16:{16:"String5"}};
```