# Compact way to use alternative keys for same value in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a compact way to have alternative keys for the same value in a dictionary?

Taking a dictionary like the following

```
dict={'A':1,'B':2,'one':1,'two':2}
```

I can obtain the value 1 using two different keys:

```
dict['A']
dict['one']
```

I would like to know if there is a more compact way to write it, something akin to:

```
dict2={['A','one']:1,['B','two']:2}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to assign the same value to multiple keys in a dict object at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974022/is-it-possible-to-assign-the-same-value-to-multiple-keys-in-a-dict-object-at-onc)

Comment: Yes, thanks, I still have to try it but it looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the dict with keys of the same value grouped as a tuple first:

```
d = {('A', 'one'): 1, ('B', 'two'): 2}
```

so that you can then convert it to the desired dict with:

```
d = {key: value for keys, value in d.items() for key in keys}
```

`d` becomes:

```
{'A': 1, 'one': 1, 'B': 2, 'two': 2}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a simple way to do it, even with a large number of keys.